# Shift processes – and are they always Markov Chains?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm not sure if I use the term "shift process" right and hence I'll first clarify what I mean with that.

Consider a sequence $(X_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of stationary (and ergodic) random variables (with values in $\mathbb{R}$). Then we could define the process $\mathcal{X}_n = (\dots,X_{n-1},X_n)$ (with values in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$), which I call the shift process of $(X_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$. (If this I use the term completely wrong, please let me know!)

By a result which we called "shifting lemma" the resulting process $\mathcal{X}_n$ is also stationary (and ergodic).

And this process also satisfies the Markov property in that sense, that for $n \geq m$ $$\mathbb{E}(\mathcal{X}_n \mid (\dots,\mathcal{X}_{m-1},\mathcal{X}_m)) = \mathbb{E}(\mathcal{X}_n \mid \mathcal{X}_m)$$
holds true, doesn't it? (My idea is that by definition of the shifting process the sigma-algebras generated by $\mathcal{X}_m$ and $(\dots,\mathcal{X}_{m-1},\mathcal{X}_m)$ are the same)

If we next consider a measurable function $h: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, then this should imply $$\mathbb{E}(h(\mathcal{X}_n) \mid (\dots,\mathcal{X}_{m-1},\mathcal{X}_m)) = \mathbb{E}(h(\mathcal{X}_n) \mid \mathcal{X}_m).$$

Hence in some sense we could understand (real-valued) Markov chains on a discrete-timespace as a generalization of processes $(h(\mathcal{X}_n))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ constructed in the sense above.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but this point of view has little interest, since $\mathbb {R}^\mathbb{N}$ is a very big state space, not practical to handle.

Comment: Good point. But we could simply adapt the setting above and choose any subset $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and assume that the $X_i$ are $\mathcal{X}$-valued. This would change the state-space to $\mathcal{X}^\mathbb{N}$ and might have more applications. (I'm thinking of $\mathcal{X} = \{0,1\}$). 

But the idea, that any shift process also satisfies the Markov property should remain valid, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, the « shift process » (following your terminology) trivially satisfies Markov property, since (as you noticed) for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the random variables $\mathcal{X}_n$ and $(\mathcal{X}_m)_{m \le n}$ carry the same information. But its a poor property in this set-up.